KOMA Grid Typesetting (Appending to Sectioning Commands)
I am working on a book using scrbook and I would like to align the body text with the grid. I understand that grid typesetting is a difficult task for LaTeX, but I cannot use ConTeXt as I need packages not available in the latter (e.g., linguistics-related).
I would like to append gridset's \vskipnextgrid to sectioning commands (e.g., \section*). Adding the following code does not work for some reason.
\usepackage{gridset}
\newcommand*{\vskipnextgridgobble}[1]{\vskipnextgrid}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup}{\vskipnextgridgobble}

Minimum Working Environment
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz, eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
            \draw[red!10!white,thin]%
            (current page.south west) grid[step=\baselineskip]%
            (current page.north east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom

\section*{Test}

\lipsum

\section*{A Very Long Title That Is Unavoidable That It Spans Multiple Lines}

\lipsum

\end{document}

I would also like some pointers as to how to implement the same with other elements such as quote environments and floats.

The do-hook heading/endgroup is much to early, AFAIK before adding the vertical space, just after printing the heading itself. An IMHO better place would be the generic LaTeX hook cmd/@afterheading/before:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz, eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
            \draw[red!10!white,thin]%
            (current page.south west) grid[step=\baselineskip]%
            (current page.north east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{gridset}
\AddToHook{cmd/@afterheading/before}{\ifvmode\vskipnextgrid\fi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom

\section*{Test}

\lipsum

\section*{A Very Long Title That Is Unavoidable That It Spans Multiple Lines}

\lipsum

\end{document}


You could use such generic hooks also for several environments (but, i.e., not for floats).
But note, that using package gridset for everything can increase the number of LaTeX runs needed to reach the final state.
So maybe an alternative would be to change all vertical spaces in a multiple of the grid distance and also \sectionlinesformat and \chapterlinesformat etc. to put the material in a box, measure that box and increase the height resp. depth to fit the grid. This would be more work, but IMHO would also allow to not only add the extra distance after the heading, but balance the distances before and after.
Note also, that gridset sometimes never terminates, e.g.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz, eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
            \draw[red!10!white,thin]%
            (current page.south west) grid[step=\baselineskip]%
            (current page.north east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{gridset}
\AddToHook{cmd/@afterheading/before}{\ifvmode\vskipnextgrid\fi}

\AddToHook{env/itemize/after}{\vskipnextgrid}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/after}{\vskipnextgrid}
\AddToHook{env/description/after}{\vskipnextgrid}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom

\blinddocument

\section*{Test}

\lipsum

\section*{A Very Long Title That Is Unavoidable That It Spans Multiple Lines}

\lipsum

\end{document}

jumps between some lines of a paragraph, one paragraph, and some lines of one paragraph + one paragraph on page 7. But
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz, eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
            \draw[red!10!white,thin]%
            (current page.south west) grid[step=\baselineskip]%
            (current page.north east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{gridset}
\AddToHook{cmd/@afterheading/before}{\ifvmode\vskipnextgrid\fi}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlist{%
    topsep=\baselineskip,%
    partopsep=\baselineskip,%
    itemsep=\baselineskip,%
    parsep=0pt
  }%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom

\blinddocument

\section*{Test}

\lipsum

\section*{A Very Long Title That Is Unavoidable That It Spans Multiple Lines}

\lipsum

\end{document}

reaches a stable state after 7 LaTeX runs. So modifying the distances added by, e.g., lists would be highly recommended.
